# Special Functions defined by Integrals.

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, special-functions, gamma-function, beta-function

There was this integral which caught my attention, when I was checking out The Applications of Beta and Gamma Functions. So, how can i prove the below, using change of variable?

$$\int_{0}^{1}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{1-x^n}} = \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{n}\frac{\Gamma(n^{-1})}{\Gamma(n^{-1}+\frac{1}{2})}$$

Thanks a lot, in advance.

Comment: Change the variable to get a form $t^a(1-t)^b$ and use Beta.

Comment: I'm a beginner, if you could guide me a few more steps..?

Comment: What change of variable can you think of ?

Comment: One suggestion, is taking t=x^n.. how do i proceed?

Comment: Like any change of variable.

Comment: I'm sorry, but i don't really understand...

Comment: Got it! I found it out.

Answer (score 0):

Start with $$I(a,b)=\int_0^1 \frac{dx}{(1-x^a)^b}$$
Then let $x=u^{1/a}$:
$$I(a,b)=\frac1a\int_0^1 u^{1/a-1}(1-u)^{-b}du$$
Which we immediately recognize as $$I(a,b)=\frac{\Gamma(\frac1a)\Gamma(1-b)}{a\Gamma(\frac1a-b)}$$
The result in question follows from the choice of $b=\frac12$ and $a=n$.

Answer (score 0):

Corrected Answer:

\begin{align*}
\int_0^1 \frac{dx}{(1-x^a)^b} &= 
\int_0^1 \frac{u^{\frac{1}{a}-1}}{a (1-u)^b} \, du\\
&=\frac{1}{a}\int_0^1 u^{\frac{1}{a}-1} (1-u)^{(1-b)-1}du\\
&=\frac{1}{a}B\left(\frac{1}{a},1-b\right),\qquad a>0,~~b<1
\end{align*}

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).